# How to make a select query that 'groups' many where statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
select `date`, `foo` from `readings` 
where `item_id` = 1 
and `date` between '2014-03-01' and '2014-03-30';
```

which returns something like this:

```
date        foo(item 1)
-----------------------
2014-03-01  2.24
2014-03-02  8.19
2014-03-03  9.63
etc
```

However, I need to repeat the query because I want to list foo columns for many items, like this:

```
date        foo(item 1)    foo(item 2)    foo(item N)
-----------------------------------------------------
```

What's the best way to make a select query that "groups" many where statements?

The only solution I've thought of so far is to run the query multiple times with different item ids, and combine in PHP, but this seems inefficient.

Comment: Just use a GROUP BY and handle the display logic in the presentation layer (assuming you have one)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
SELECT DATE,
CASE WHEN ITEM_ID = 1 AND DATE BETWEEN SO AND SO THEN FOO END AS FOO_1,
CASE WHEN ITEM_ID = 2 AND DATE BETWEEN SO AND SO THEN FOO END AS FOO_2,
CASE WHEN ITEM_ID = 3 AND DATE BETWEEN SO AND SO THEN FOO END AS FOO_3
.
.
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the data for each result row comes from different table rows, you need to join the table to itself for each item.

Assuming data exists for all items for every date in the range:

```
select t1.date, t1.foo foo_t1, t2.foo foo_t2, ..., tn.foo foo_tn
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.date = t1.date and t2.item = 2
...
join mytable tn on tn.date = t1.date and tn.item = n
where t1.item = 1
and t1.date between '2014-03-01' and '2014-03-30'
```

If some items numbers (other than 1) are missing for some dates, use `left join` instead of `join`.

If 1 may also be missing for some dates, you'll need to get a list of dates from somewhere and left join everything to that.